# How to securely manage generating files on the client-side to download

Tags: web-application, php, webserver, client-side

While searching for a way to convert an HTML table to .CSV file, I found there are 2 ways to generate files to download on the client side with JavaScript:

1. using [data URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)
2. by generating the file on the client side and posting it to the server which will merely echo the posted file back to trigger the download process normally. something like  [this](https://github.com/rubo77/table2CSV#option-31---generate-csv-file) or [this](https://tutorialzine.com/2011/05/generating-files-javascript-php).

I can't use the first option (data url) because it's [IE browser support limitations to images and linked resources like CSS or JS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri), so I'm going with the second option (generating the file on the client , post it to the server, echo it back to the client), I was thinking of something like this PHP script

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$_POST['fileName']}");
die($_POST['file']); 
?>
```

How an attacker might exploit this script ?

Does this vulnerability has a known name I can search for ?

Comment: I think passing "things" for the client side and then let them to be uploaded to the server always is a risk.